# Hotencoded values & DataFrame for logistic regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a logistic regression on a dataset that has features with some categorical values. In order to process those features through regression, I was planning to encode them

```
#Select categorical features only & encode name numerically with LabelEncoder
cat_features = df.select_dtypes(include=[object])

label_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_features = cat_features.apply(label_enc.fit_transform)

#Aggregate all encoded values into a binary matrix
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(le_features)
final_cat_features = enc.transform(le_features).toarray()
```

After running this code, I do confirm it returns an encoded matrix

```
(4665, 290)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

This is where I get stuck. How I am supposed to regenerate a dataframe from that exactly?! Should I concatenate the 290 columns together in order to end up with a new feature to add to my new dataframe? If not, I have to say I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add all 290 columns to your dataframe with the remaining (i.e. non-categorical or numerical) values. For that you can create a dataframe from the array and join it to the original dataframe:

```
final_cat_features_df = pd.DataFrame(final_cat_features, index=df.index)
df = df.join(final_cat_features_df)
```

As an alternative, you may want to have a look at pandas [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).